# Android Studio with multiple monitors

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio

Is it possible to make Android Studio work with multiple monitors of different resolutions?

I am trying to move from Eclipse to Android Studio but have a laptop with 2560x1600 panel and an external display 1920x1080.

With eclipse I can undock sections and move them to the other monitor and as with everything else I move between monitors, after more than 50% has move to the next display, it re scales to the corresponding monitor resolution.

When I try to move floating windows from Android Studio to the next display they keep the resolution that the main window is set to, either too small and unreadable if the main window is on my 1920x1080 display or over sized if the other way round.

Using Windows 8 on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for this issue at this moment. On [Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/high-density-display-with-android-studio) says, that:

>
On Windows, Android Studio should provide the best experience in all configurations, except for configurations with multiple monitors having different DPI (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186007).